# Why do multi-class logistic regression model coefficients change depending on class labels?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm currently training a multi-class logistic regression model with scikit-learn and need the model coefficients for a subsequent feature selection pipeline. However, changing the class labels that should be predicted leads to different coefficients. So if I want to predict three classes with the labels 0, 1, 2 the results are different compared to naming them e.g. 2, 0, 1.

To demonstrate this problem, I tested the example from the scikit-learn documentation:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV
X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
clf = LogisticRegressionCV(cv=5, random_state=0).fit(X, y)
```

There are three classes in this example:

```
import numpy as np
np.unique(y)
>>> array([0, 1, 2])
```

I renamed the class labels such that they have a different order and trained a second model with the renamed labels:

```
y_rename_dict = {0: 2, 1: 0, 2: 1}
y1 = np.array([y_rename_dict[i] for i in y])
clf1 = LogisticRegressionCV(cv=5, random_state=0).fit(X, y1)
```

Looking at the `coef_` values of both models reveals different results for each of the predicted classes (taking the different ordering of the coefficient arrays into account):

```
clf.coef_
>>> array([[-0.34022169,  2.46767758, -4.95392813, -2.48912258],
       [ 1.15417403,  0.09965468, -0.50367445, -2.92399758],
       [-0.81395234, -2.56733226,  5.45760258,  5.41312016]])
clf1.coef_
>>> array([[ 1.16881994,  0.10139304, -0.50578412, -2.92007532],
       [-0.79861288, -2.56336652,  5.4577491 ,  5.41271211],
       [-0.37020706,  2.46197348, -4.95196498, -2.49263679]])
```

To show the magnitude of difference between these results, I took a look at the sum of the absolute values of the coefficients:

```
max(np.sum(np.abs(clf.coef_), axis=0) - np.sum(np.abs(clf1.coef_), axis=0))
>>> 0.007931465905081758
```

In this example, the difference is not that big but with increasing numbers of features and samples, the differences become more noticeable. I also tested the `SGDClassifier` model with 'log' loss but it also leads to different results depending on the order of the class labels.

I was not able to find any explanation for this behavior. Is this a common problem of this model or is there maybe a solution to fix this issue?

Comment: It's a stretch to call this a problem. There's stochasticity in the optimization process. This could come down to, for instance, arbitrarily broken ties early in the optimization process. If these are the difference between your model performing well or not, you're vastly overfitting.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm aware of the stochasticity in these optimization processes and that we cannot assume these models to be 100% deterministic. However, I still think that this is a problem since the observed class label-dependency of the feature coefficients could introduce biases that many users might not be aware of. As far as I know, applying permutations to the class labels is not an approach that is generally used to test the robustness of a trained model or evaluate the impact of certain features.